# Issue on updating Linux Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, libreoffice

As LU is strongly suggesting me, I want to update my packages but a problem (which I hadn't encountered before) interrupts upgrading process. Some specific packages fail to be downloaded. They are: `LibiCu25, LibreOffice-Calc 4.2.8, LibreOffice-Common 4.2.8, LibreOffice-Writer4.2.8` and some other LibreOffice related packages.
Other packages are downloaded normally, but when it comes to download LibreOffice things it fails, then the whole process stops.
I several times tried `apt-get clean, autoclean, autoremove` and restarting my computer, but nothing changed.
I also tried to deselect every LibreOffice option on Software Updater menu but they showed up again during process. The very same thing happens while trying to update on command line.
Can you help me what I should exactly to update/upgrade my system normally without failure?

Comment: The Python question is unrelated to the first so it should be [asked separately](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). I'd edit this question and then ask a new one for the Python issue.

Comment: @Anthony Geoghegan edited ...

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get remove libreoffice` first.

After upgrading, re-install libreoffice.

Comment: The code you provided returns an error: `E: Package 'libreoffice' is not installed, so not removed.` But I've got it.